# Storing characters in an array, C

Tags: c, arrays, file, function, struct

I'm doing a school project and for it I need to get a random film title and replace the characters with asterisks and the user will have to guess the film later in the program, kind of like hangman.

In the following function I'm trying to randomly generate a film title and then store it. Then I want to convert the letters to asterisks and store them in their own array for use later in the program.

However, I have been having absolutely no luck with this!I've been at it for a long time and I just can't think of how to go about this! I know the code itself is probably terrible but I felt I had to post something to get the idea across.

Thanks!

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>

typedef struct {
            char title[500];
            char hiddentitle[500];
        }Title;

char Film(Title t){

FILE *fopen(), *fp;

    fp = fopen("Film.txt", "r");

    int i=0;
    int j;
    int number;
    int lenMovie;
    char c, film;
    char movies[45][500];
    int val =0;


    while( i<45 ){

        fgets(movies[i], sizeof(movies[i]), fp);
        i++;

    }

    srand(time(NULL));
    number = (1+(rand() % 45));

    t.title[500] = movies[number];


    printf("%s", t.title);
    lenMovie = strlen(t.title);

    while(val <= lenMovie)
    {
        c = t.title[val];

        if(c >= 'a' && c<= 'z'){


            t.hiddentitle[val] == '*';
        }

        else if(c >= 'A' && c<= 'Z'){

            t.hiddentitle[val] == '*';
        }
        else{

            t.hiddentitle[val] == c;
        }

        val++;
    }
    printf("\n%s", t.hiddentitle);
    fclose(fp);
}

int main(void){
    Title t;

    Film (t);

    }
```

Comment: What is your aim with the `FILE *fopen(), ...` call? You shouldn't be calling `fopen` with no arguments...

Comment: The line `t.title[500] = movies[number];` is accessing field 'title' of bounds, maybe you want to do `strcpy(t.title, movies[number])`

Comment: Oh, that's just how I was taught really, we were never told why.. It usually works?

Comment: Okay, using strcpy(t.title, movies[number]) worked really well, thank you, it's now printing the movie. My next challenge is the asterisks!

Comment: Before that, you might want to remove the `1 + ` for your `number` assignment on the previous line. You wouldn't want it to be possibly `45`, while it would be desirable to have a `0`.

Comment: Familiarize yourself with the concept of [Hamming distance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hamming_distance) as that's what your game is effectively based on. The following may confuse you but it's worth a try: You don't have to store the "starred" title; you can process it right before you show it to the user. That would lead to less complicated code for me, but of course it depends on what you're comfortable with. Good idea in general, keep it up.

Answer (score 0):

This code:

```
char title[500];
char movies[45][500];
...
t.title[500] = movies[number];
```

has 3 fatal errors in it:

- `title` is `char[500]` (string) and `movies` is `char[45][500]` (array of 45 strings), you are working with different types
- you can not copy strings with assignment in C
- even if previous 2 could be ignored somehow, elements in an array are being indexed from `0`, i.e. `title` contains `char`s stored at indexes from `0` to `499`.

What you probably meant to do was:

```
strcpy(t.title, movies[number]);
```

---

Also note that

```
FILE *fopen()
```

doesn't declare a variable, it declares a function that takes no arguments and returns a pointer to `FILE` ( see *"most vexing parse"* ) and since you never call `fopen` with no arguments (which compiler should not even allow you to do), this declaration is completely useless.